# AutocompleteUI + jQuery On-Screen Keyboard

Tags: jquery, callback, keyboard, virtual

I have search field and virtual keyboard. After input some letter from my desktop keyboard, all work correct, and print result in separate div.

When I want to get result, write some letters or words from virtual keyboard, nothing happens. I understood that I need to use a callback on this virtual keyboard. But I find it difficult to do! Thanks in advance!

Autocomplete code:

```
var some_array = [  {...},
                        {...},
                        ...];
$(function() {
    $("#tags").autocomplete({
        source: some_array,
        autoFocus: true,
        minLength: 0,
        delay: 400,
        suggest: function(items) {
            $('.results').hide(); 
            $(".results").empty();
            for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++){
                var person = $('<div id="pers" style="pers"><img src="./img/photo/'+ items[i].value +'.jpg" class="photo_preview">'+ items[i].label +'<br /><br /><small>'+ items[i].desc +'</small></div>');
                $(".results").append(person);
            }
            $(".results").show(200);
        }
    });    
});
```

Small part of library keyboard, when triggered after pressing:

```
write: function(m) {
           var a = jsKeyboard.currentElement.val(),
           b = String.fromCharCode(m),
           pos = jsKeyboard.currentElementCursorPosition,
           output = [a.slice(0, pos), b, a.slice(pos)].join('');
           jsKeyboard.currentElement.val(output);
           jsKeyboard.currentElementCursorPosition++; //+1 cursor
           jsKeyboard.updateCursor();
       }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't put up the right listener, solved the problem differently. Installed the extension for chrome Virtual Keyboard and there is no problem. P. S. develops software for the touchscreen panels, not for public, so for 1 workstation is ideal. Thank you all.